# When I add Jquery to my page, there will be error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am changing the page of portfolios. I am adding video popup feature to my pages... To do that, I have to add JQuery to my pages, but, when I was added, then, the page was created errors like that: [image: error ss] However, if I am deleting the code that is on below, everything is okay...

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-tA8y0XqiwnpwmOIl3SGAcFl2RvxHjA8qp0+1uCGmRmg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

What can I do??

Thanks!

EDIT:

The codes are below:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://foo.com/wp-content/themes/bridge/lboxfiles/magnific-popup.css">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-tA8y0XqiwnpwmOIl3SGAcFl2RvxHjA8qp0+1uCGmRmg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<script src="http://foo.com/wp-content/themes/bridge/lboxfiles/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>

<script>
(function() {
    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
        disableOn: 700,
        type: 'iframe',
        mainClass: 'mfp-fade',
        removalDelay: 160,
        preloader: false,
        fixedContentPos: false
    });
});
</script>
<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where you put this? before closing `</body>`?

Comment: Is something else using $?

Comment: I updated my post. Yes something used, but when I delete the jquery link, everything will work successfully...

Comment: `However, if I am deleting the code that is on below, everything is okay` - that's your solution, don't include that line, because, as you say **everything is ok** - perhaps you have loaded jquery some other way some how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this just after importing jQuery

```
$.noConflict()
```

More precisely

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js" integrity="sha256-tA8y0XqiwnpwmOIl3SGAcFl2RvxHjA8qp0+1uCGmRmg=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script> $.noConflict() </script>
```

Then modify this line

```
    $('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
```

to

```
    jQuery('.popup-youtube, .popup-vimeo, .popup-gmaps').magnificPopup({
```